# PostgreSQL on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have my database.yml with a default environment:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  username: postgres
  password: 123
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
```

When I try to create my db i received the error:

> connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
> Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

I'm trying to create a database with postgresql with rails application.

Comment: can you connect with pgadmin?

Comment: Do you actually have a database running on localhost?